# How to bind a placeholder in span Angular2+

Tags: angular

Im my situation I just want to bind a placeholder in a span. It's working perfectly when I use an input but I have to do it in a editable span

```
<span 
  #newComment 
  class="postcomment"
  contenteditable="true"
  [placeholder]="'Comment.Write'|translate"
  // it's working if I don't bind it like this : placeholder="your comment"
>
</span>
```

My error is :

```
Can't bind to 'placeholder' since it isn't a known property of 'span'
```

Thank you if you have the solution. And i can't use an input :)

Comment: Placeholder isn't valid for span elements.

Comment: Yes but right now it's working but not when I want to bind it. I just want to know if I have a way to do it

Comment: You can't bind since it's not valid. If you want you can manually change the element using @ViewChild decorator or a Directive.

Comment: But keep in mind that since it's not a valid attribute it probably won't work in some or most of browsers.

Comment: Ok thank you @EliasSoares, I'm gonna use a ngif :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commenters have made clear, the `placeholder` attribute is not a valid for `<span>` elements, even with the `contenteditable` attribute.

As you are set on `contenteditable`, in your code  where you are setting the `innerHTML` or `innerText` you could inject a placeholder template if the data is blank. You would then need to then bind to the on focus events and clear/re-add this template on focus in & out.

If you are using this regularly, wrapping this in a directive would suit you best. A quick short example;

**Component.ts code**

```
comment = null; // When comment is null, the template will be shown
template = 'Please enter your comment...';
```

**Component.html code**

```
<span
    #newComment
    (focusin)="comment = (comment === null ? '' : comment)"
    (focusout)="newComment.innerText.trim() === '' ? comment = null : comment = newComment.innerHTML"
    [innerHTML]="comment === null ? template : comment"
    contenteditable="true">
</span>
```